# Print range of ROWS in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to print a range of rows in a large dataset but everything comes back with an error mentioning columns. I've tried a variation of punctuation but struggling to find anything that dictates the actual syntax for print `rows` and not columns. Can someone assist?

```
INDIANA.LONG <- INDIANA %>% 
  pivot_longer(X2010:X2019, names_to = "YEARS", values_to = "COUNT") %>%
  print[75:83,]
```

This is the error:

```
Error in `vectbl_as_col_location()`:
! Can't subset columns past the end.
ℹ Locations 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, … don't
  exist.
ℹ There are only 6 columns.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `slice` from `dplyr` before the `print` statement:

```
INDIANA.LONG <- INDIANA %>% 
  pivot_longer(X2010:X2019, names_to = "YEARS", values_to = "COUNT") %>%
  slice(75:83) %>%
  print
```

Answer (score 0):

within a `dplyr`/`tidyr` pipeline, you can use `between()`, `row_number()`, and `filter()`

```
filter(between(row_number(), 75,83))
```

instead of your `print()` call.

Comment: That doesn't print those rows though.

Comment: i don't think you want to assign this to anything.  i.e. dont assign the filter or the slice statement to anything.  instead assign the pivot_longer to the INDIANA.LONG, and then, if you want to look at rows 75 to 83, execute this filter, or equivalently, the slice call in the other solution on the INDIANA.LONG object without assigning it to anything

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the base R notation inside the pipe prior to using `print`:

```
library(dplyr)

INDIANA.LONG <- INDIANA %>%
  pivot_longer(X2010:X2019, names_to = "YEARS", values_to = "COUNT") %>%
  .[75:83, ] %>%
  print
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the question - had to rewrite the `pivot_longer` function. Thanks everyone!

```
INDIANA.LONG <-  pivot_longer(data= INDIANA, cols= (X2010:X2019), names_to = "YEARS", values_to = "COUNT")

INDIANA.LONG[75:83,]
```